# How to avoid invalid traffic, AdMob Ads

Tags: android, admob

I've created an admob account latel,y I did my best to avoid ad serving limits because I was told that it is improtant to be careful about it from a friend. so I did all my best to avoid any violation.

So I used gabbing (cab limit) to limit how many times my unit will be shown to same user. I chose to show the ad 3 times for every 30 minutes to the same user, it worked, but then I've noticed that impressions is little compared to requests, so I've decided to raise the amount of impressions so I make it 4 times for 30 minutes.

After doing that I've got a message from AdMob saying "the ad serving is limited for your app"

Note: I suspect that a group of shady users wants to do harm to my app, by reporting it to AdMob or by intentionally clicking on my ads to generate invalid clicks.

What should I do?

Comment: Hi Jabbar, have you find solution of it ? if resolved then help me to resolve same problem

Answer (score 1):

Just skip the AdMob and don't use them.

They don't provide you any explanation, no feedback, no details, no support. Google does not like you earning the money. I have been fighting with this invalid traffic (with integration tests and not launching the app locally for months & limiting ads programatically) without success.

I recommend using AppLovin or different ad provider to just avoid the hassle.

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1**:- 1 ad for every 10 minutes to the same user.
**Step 2**:- Don't share(link or apk) the app on Social media.
**Step 3**:- Don't change AppId or AdUnitID.
**Step 4**:- AppId or AdUnitID use for single app.
**Step 5**:- Same AppId or AdUnitId not use multiple app.
**Step 6**:- Don't run any Ad campaigns.
**Step 7**:- uninstall the app on family and friends' phones.
**Step 8**:- Use ads mediation unity.

Comment: Why don't share the link on social media, how it's related with the issue?